# Can I use a semicolon instead of a period in short sentences or with fragments?

Tags: punctuation, semicolons

For instance, is the semicolon correct in the following sentences?

1. Alright; let me see what I can do.
2. Thank you; I hope you have a good day, too.
3. Thank you; you too! (as a response to someone)
4. No; we will pass by my place first.

Thank you so much.

Comment: In numbers 1 and 4, the right punctuation is a comma. A semicolon or a period is too heavy.

Comment: I'm not too happy with the semicolon in (1), but that may be influenced by knowing the divided opinions on the acceptability of 'alright'. I'd prefer a comma or a full stop; the semicolon seems too long or too short for my chosen speech gap. I'd prefer a dash in (3). I'd use the semicolon or a full stop (to signal a longer pause) in (2), and feel any sensible punctuation (other than zero) works in (4). _But if you're looking for *the correct answer**, forget it. Punctuation around fragments is a grey area, and often different options are equally acceptable to many Anglophones.

Comment: If you can use a period, you can also use a semicolon.

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaborate answer @EdwinAshworth.

Comment: Thank you so much, Peter and Jason.

Comment: @Jason [LiveWriteThrive](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=PzdJX7nFA42U8gL1tZ_YDQ&q=semicolon+incorrect+use&oq=semicolon+incorrect+use&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzICCAAyCAgAEBYQChAeMgYIABAWEB46BAgAEEc6BQgAEJECOgQIABAKUNAzWPFOYMhRaABwAXgAgAFmiAHuBpIBBDEyLjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwj54Pf5rr7rAhUNilwKHfXaB9sQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) has: << Incorrect: He lost his money at the slot machines; every single penny.  >> And I tend to agree.  But there are few who would criticise ' He lost his money at the slot machines.  Every single penny.'